# Error: Expected resource of type string [ResourceType] // about.getComLogo().toString()

Tags: java, android, android-studio, helper

please help how can i solve that in `\AboutActivity.java`

in the line :

```
imageLoader.DisplayImage(Constant.SERVER_IMAGE_NEWSLISTDETAILS+about.getComLogo().toString(), imglogo);
```

the problem in messages gradle builder :

> Error:Error: Expected resource of type string [ResourceType]

Comment: Please give more context. Try to include a runnable example which allows to reproduce your error.

Comment: bro thank you for your reply but i didn't understand !! :(

Comment: the msg : of the errore :     'about.getComLogo().toString()' is redundant less... (Ctrl+F1) 
Reports any to call toString() on a String object. This is entirely redundant.

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.freeimages.hdpicturs;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.hdpictursfree.imageloader.ImageLoader;
import com.hdpictursfree.item.ItemAbout;
import com.hdpictursfree.util.AlertDialogManager;
import com.hdpictursfree.util.Constant;
import com.hdpictursfree.util.JsonUtils;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AboutActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    ImageView imglogo;
    TextView txtappname,txtcomemail,txtcomsite;
    WebView webcomdes;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader; 
    JsonUtils util;
    List<ItemAbout> listabout;
    AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();
    Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.about);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) this.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("About Us");
        this.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        imglogo=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_comlogo);
        txtappname=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_appname);
        txtcomemail=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_comemail);
        txtcomsite=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_comwebsite);
        webcomdes=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView_comdes);
        webcomdes.getSettings().setDefaultTextEncodingName("UTF-8");
        listabout=new ArrayList<ItemAbout>();


        imageLoader=new ImageLoader(getApplicationContext());

        util=new JsonUtils(getApplicationContext());


        if (JsonUtils.isNetworkAvailable(AboutActivity.this)) {
            new MyTask().execute(Constant.COMPANY_DETAILS_URL);
        } else {
            showToast("No Network Connection!!!");
            alert.showAlertDialog(AboutActivity.this, "Internet Connection Error",
                    "Please connect to working Internet connection", false);
        }

    }
    private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        ProgressDialog pDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AboutActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            return JsonUtils.getJSONString(params[0]);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if (null != pDialog && pDialog.isShowing()) {
                pDialog.dismiss();
            }

            if (null == result || result.length() == 0) {
                showToast("Server Connection Error");
                alert.showAlertDialog(AboutActivity.this, "Server Connection Error",
                        "May Server Under Maintaines Or Low Network", false);

            } else {

                try {
                    JSONObject mainJson = new JSONObject(result);
                    JSONArray jsonArray = mainJson.getJSONArray(Constant.CATEGORY_ARRAY_NAME);
                    JSONObject objJson = null;
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        objJson = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        ItemAbout objItem = new ItemAbout();


                        objItem.setAppName(objJson.getString(Constant.COMPANY_DETAILS_APPNAME));
                        objItem.setComEmail(objJson.getString(Constant.COMPANY_DETAILS_COMMAIL));
                        objItem.setComWebsite(objJson.getString(Constant.COMPANY_DETAILS_COMSITE));
                        objItem.setComDes(objJson.getString(Constant.COMPANY_DETAILS_COMDES));
                        objItem.setComLogo(objJson.getString(Constant.COMPANY_DETAILS_COMLOGO));

                        listabout.add(objItem);

                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                setAdapterToListview();
            }

        }
    }

    public void setAdapterToListview() {

        ItemAbout about=listabout.get(0);
        txtappname.setText(about.getAppName());
        txtcomemail.setText(about.getComEmail());
        txtcomsite.setText(about.getComWebsite());


        String mimeType = "text/html";
        String encoding = "utf-8";
        String htmlText = about.getComDes();


        String text = "<html><head>"
                + "<style type=\"text/css\">body{color: #1C1C1C;}"
                + "</style></head>"
                + "<body>"  
                +  htmlText
                + "</body></html>";

        webcomdes.loadData(text, mimeType, encoding);
        webcomdes.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(getString(R.color.background_color)));

        imageLoader.DisplayImage(Constant.SERVER_IMAGE_NEWSLISTDETAILS+about.getComLogo().toString(), imglogo);
    }

    public void showToast(String msg) {
        Toast.makeText(AboutActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem)
    {       
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) 
        {
        case android.R.id.home: 
            onBackPressed();
            break;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem);
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```